# Displaying a useful message when redirected to FormsAuthentication logon page with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, http-status-code-401, authorize-attribute

I want to make a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that includes a `Message` property. The problem is, my FormsAuthentication redirects to the specified loginUrl. How can that View get access to the attribute's Message property?

for example, I have this action using my custom AuthorizeAttribute

```
[Authorize(Message="You must be logged in to see user settings.")]
public ActionResult Settings()
{
    return View();
}
```

which gets redirected to /Account/LogOn (thanks to the `FormsAuthentication` settings in web.config) if the user is not logged in. I want to show the "You must be logged in to see user settings" on the LogOn View so the user knows *why* they were redirected to the LogOn page

Comment: What do you need to do?  Do you need to pass a string from the controller to the view?

Comment: from the controller attribute to the view that it causes a redirect to. not from the Settings action to the Settings view, but instead from the Settings action attribute to the LogOn view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to put the value of your Message property into TempData in the HandleUnautherizeRequest method of your custom AuthorizeAttribute. Then in the LogOn action on your Account controller take the value from TempData and put it into the ViewBag or your model so that the View has access to it.

**AuthorizeAttribute:**

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{            
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    filterContext.Controller.TempData["MessageFromMyAttribute"] = this.Message;
}
```

**AccountController**

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    ViewBag.AttributeMessage = TempData["MessageFromMyAttribute"];
    return View();
}
```

Because MVC is doing a redirect behind the scenes the value in TempData will persist across the redirect.

Comment: ...which is pretty much what Tomas just said about a minute earlier :)

Comment: I considered including a code example, but decided to go for first answer instead ;) (Probably wouldn't have gotten the code right on the fly anyway...)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect. I never knew what `TempData` was for - I always saw it in intellisense, decided it was not relevant, and ignored it from that point on. Now I know :)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Create your own attribute, that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`
2. In your filter, add the message to `TempData`
3. In the action that you redirect to when login is required, get the message from `TempData` and pass it to the view.